Postgres: automatic action (increment count of foreign key) after update
How to automate an update in a table, after a change in another table ?
Say (please see below) I have a table countries, and a table cities. How to make that, when adding a city in table cities, the total column is automatically updated (incremented for the corresponding city) in the table countries ?
Kind of :
BEGIN; INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Tokyo', 'Japan'); UPDATE countries SET total=1 WHERE name='Japan'; COMMIT;
, but automatic, do a countries.the_city.total++ when adding cities.the_city.
Countries:
postgres=# SELECT * FROM countries;
 name  | total 
-------+-------
 USA   |     0
 Japan |     0
(2 rows)

Cities:
postgres=# SELECT * FROM cities;
 name | country                                                                                                                                                          
------+---------                                                                                                                                                         
(0 rows)    

Commands:
CREATE DATABASE geo;
\c geo;
CREATE TABLE countries (
    name VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY,
    total int
);
CREATE TABLE cities (
    name VARCHAR(15),
    country VARCHAR(15),
    FOREIGN KEY (country) REFERENCES countries(name)
);

Context:
Standard SQL, or Postgres v16

If you want to keep a redundant copy of your data, use a trigger to update the copy (in this case, the total count) wherever a city is added or removed.

@LaurenzAlbe Yes, there is some redundancy, countries.the_country.total = COUNT(cities.country) WHERE cities.country==the_country . But how to make such a trigger ?

The redundant information is best maintained with a trigger.
You should first make sure that total has a reasonable default value:
ALTER TABLE countries
   ALTER total SET DEFAULT 0,
   ALTER total SET NOT NULL;

Then a trigger to maintain the count could look like this:
CREATE FUNCTION count_trig() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
      UPDATE countries SET total = total - 1
      WHERE name = OLD.country;
   END IF;

   IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
      UPDATE countries SET total = total + 1
      WHERE name = NEW.country;
   END IF;

   RETURN coalesce(NEW, OLD);
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER count_trig BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON cities
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION count_trig();

This is just an example. There is room for improvement: you can for example skip processing for updates that don't modify the country name. You could add additional triggers to make the solution more bulletproof, like add a trigger that prevents updating total unless the update was called by a trigger.
